# How do I install pipwin properly, it installs but then it's not recognized as a command

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

So I am trying to install pyaudio and it gives the _portaudio error, so people online told me to install it through pipwin, so I run this command:

```
pip install pipwin
```

Then when i type:

```
pipwin install pyaudio
```

This shows up:

```
'pipwin' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

So i reboot, thinking that's the problem. Same message. Then I go ahead and uninstall pipwin and installs it again to find any potential errors that I missed. This shows up in red text:

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
conda-repo-cli 1.0.4 requires pathlib, which is not installed.
anaconda-project 0.10.1 requires ruamel-yaml, which is not installed.
cookiecutter 1.7.2 requires Jinja2<3.0.0, but you have jinja2 3.0.3 which is incompatible.
cookiecutter 1.7.2 requires MarkupSafe<2.0.0, but you have markupsafe 2.0.1 which is incompatible.
```

Now I think oh, let's just install pathlib.

```
pip install pathlib
```

but then, ofcourse it's not that easy:

```
Collecting pathlib
  Using cached pathlib-1.0.1.tar.gz (49 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      ERROR: Can not execute `setup.py` since setuptools is not available in the build environment.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

So i go ahead and try downloading setup tools, only for this to happen:

```
Collecting setuptools
  Downloading setuptools-60.10.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 1.1/1.1 MB 8.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: setuptools
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
spyder 5.1.5 requires pyqt5<5.13, which is not installed.
spyder 5.1.5 requires pyqtwebengine<5.13, which is not installed.
conda-repo-cli 1.0.4 requires pathlib, which is not installed.
anaconda-project 0.10.1 requires ruamel-yaml, which is not installed.
astroid 2.6.6 requires wrapt<1.13,>=1.11, but you have wrapt 1.13.3 which is incompatible.
Successfully installed setuptools-60.10.0
```

What is happening, why is it failing. Even more of a mindblow is that this is like 3 levels of just errors, trying to install PyAudio. Please help, this worked before I switched hard drives and had to reinstall Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when i install a module, i have to use `py -m pip install {module}` after `cd C:\`. Also make sure you have latest versions on pip.